# Не удается раздать статику с nginx

Tags: nginx

Сконфигурировал сервер на отдачу статики, получаю "403 Forbidden"

Мой конфиг:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http{
    server{
        location / {
            root /home/danya/Desktop/data/www;
        }
        location /images/ {
            root /home/danya/Desktop/data;
}   }   }
```

Пробовал ходить на http//localhost/index.html , http//localhost/home/danya/Desktop/data/www/index.html ,
http//localhost/home/danya/Desktop/data/images/1.jpg

```
[danya@stdfx_arch data]$ tree
.
├── images
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.gif
│   └── 3.png
└── www
    └── index.html
```

/home/danya/Desktop/data

В чем может быть дело?Может я с расположением статики накосячил?

Comment: у nginx-то права на чтение есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пользователь, от имени которого запущен процесс *nginx*, не имеет доступа к файлам/каталогам, которые вы указали.

возможные варианты выхода (в порядке убывания степени разумности):

1. расположить файлы в более подходящем месте (часто — в `/var/www/`) и сделать их владельцем пользователя, от имени которого запущен процесс *nginx*.
2. запускать процесс *nginx* от имени того пользователя/группы, который имеет доступ (хотя бы на чтение) к нужным вам файлам/каталогам.
3. изменить права доступа к нужным вам файлам/каталогам так, чтобы пользователь, от имени которого работает *nginx*, имел к ним доступ хотя бы на чтение.